# How to get full file path of magento file using FIREBUG or INSPECT. Mozilla extension. Is there any way.

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, edit

I am using editor Firebug extension of Mozilla to do temporary editing of my website pages. It is really easy to edit through Firebug & also it is very difficult to locate the file which we are editing. Magento website file structure is very difficult to understand. Is there any way to locate the file which we are editing through Firebug & edit that file for permanent changes. The provided answers does not giving me all full location of files which is i am editing. So is there any easy way to recognize the location of file in Magento file structure.

Comment: Enable template path hints by following the reference http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Comment: Krishna i had already done that.

Comment: Can you tell me "elements on my site" ?

Comment: Yeah,  you go to my website bookslab.in. You can find the "Welcome to the bookslab...." section on the top of the webpage. So that section & most of the section is unable to locate using firebug

Comment: @ Salman Dalal Please check the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply enable Template Path Hints by:

- logging to the backend
- access System > Configuration > Developer
- switch the store view to your current store by using the top left scope switcher
- set Template Hints Path to Yes in the Debug section

Comment: Thanks for answer Raphael. I had already installed Template Path Hints. But, still i can't find file locations of some of the elements on my site.

Comment: @SalmanDalal the template Hints should give you the path of the templates. Please edit your question by explaining which elements you can't find as your question will most likely be closed because unclear

Comment: Okzz raphael i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

We have a `grep` command to search the exact string among the files.

For example in the welcome message has class called `welcome-msg`

> grep -i -n -r "welcome-msg" magento_root/app/design

If it is a Welcome message, no code is needed for this.

> Go to System - Configuration - General - Design - Header

Comment: How to use this

Comment: Are you working on linnux or windows ?

Comment: I am working on windows

Comment: You can check with https://www.mkyong.com/linux/grep-for-windows-findstr-example/

Comment: On this link there are only Linux commands & i am working on windows

Comment: Please check it for windows https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/equivalent-of-unix-grep-command-in-doswindows-726

Comment: If you are using notepad ++ , you can go with search -> Find in files OR Ctrl + Shift + F in notepad ++.

Comment: Okzz will check & let you know

Comment: Can you answer my this question as well. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142812/i-want-to-refresh-the-page-automatically-if-users-clicks-on-check-button

I had tried a lot, but it not happining

Comment: Okzz i will let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47671/discussion-between-salman-dalal-and-krishna-ijjada-at-i95dev).

Comment: Hey! krishna did you see my new question

Comment: Yeap finally thanks, now can you help me in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142812/i-want-to-refresh-the-page-automatically-if-users-clicks-on-check-button

Comment: Yeap. So can you help me in that question

Comment: Okzz  no problem

Comment: Krishna did you checked my question