# how to reload the page everytime when user clicks button

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, ajax, jquery, zipcode

I am building an ecommerce magento site named [www.bookslab.in](http://bookslab.in). I had one issue in this website. I want to make compulsory for every user to check their zipcode before they buy anything from the website, because i am delivering the products in the limited area. Now i had added the exception for that. The exception is when user's zipcode is invalid then ADD_TO_CART button is disabled, this is the exception. So, the problem comes here when user checks that the zipcode he enters is wrong, so after that he enters the correct zipcode, but still the ADD_TO_CART button is disabled. **To solved this issue, i want to refresh(reload) the page everytime when user clicks on CHECK button of zipcode field.** Plz suggest me in the code i provided & go to my website to see the problem.

cod.phtml

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 **************************************
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                          jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      zipcode='';

                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to refresh the page automatically if users clicks on CHECK button](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142812/i-want-to-refresh-the-page-automatically-if-users-clicks-on-check-button)

Comment: It is not duplicate gopal in that question the problem is different, & in this there is a new problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try after replacing your script code with the following code. You don't need to refresh the page to enable the button.

```
<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                          jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                       jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr('disabled');

                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now when the user will enter the correct code, the add to cart button will  automatically get enabled without refreshing the page.

Comment: Knowband i need to refresh the page to make the add_to_cart button enabled after it getting disabled if user enter does not enter the correct zipcode. did you get now!

Comment: I want add to cart button enabled only when zipcode is valid otherwise it should be disabled if zipcode is wrong

Comment: Any answer to this

Comment: any answer stackys!

Comment: Any answer guys

Comment: Is it not disabling the button when zip code is wrong?

Comment: It is disabling the add to cart button & if again if user enter the correct zipcode then the disabled button has to be enabled automatically if zipcode is correct

Comment: Any answer stackys

Comment: Any answer stackys

Comment: Add to cart button is getting disabled but again if user enter the correct zipcode then the disabled button is not getting enabled automatically if zipcode is correct –

Comment: Any answer stackys

Comment: Any answer to this question stackys

Comment: We have updated the answer, check if it works

Comment: Knowband Plugins u rock man really I m impressed! Thank you & sorry for the late reply!